# How to set load store in Buffered grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a grid store where I am using `Ext.data.Store` and loading the value. below is the method where I am giving a post requesting, getting the data and loading by using `store.on(load)`.

```
myGridStore: function(myXml) {
        var me = this,store;
        me.setLoading(true);
        store = new Ext.data.Store({
            proxy: new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
                actionMethods: { 
                    read: 'POST'
                },
                url: 'someUrl',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'I',
                    rootProperty: 'R'
                },
                extraParams: {
                    strIPXML: myXml
                }
            }),
            sortOnLoad : true,
            autoLoad: true,
            remoteFilter: false,
            multiSelect: true,          
            fields: me.fields,
        });
        store.on('load', function(thistore, records , successful , operation , eOpts){
                me.store.loadData(thistore.data.items);
        });

        return store;
    },
```

now I want my store to `bufferedStore` so for that I changed `Ext.data.Store` to `Ext.data.BufferedStore` But in bufferedStore I can not use `store.on(load)` Like I commented the code, below is the code and then grid is loading. But when second time I am applying the `myXml` I am not able to set the data because `store.on(load)` is not working.

```
myGridStore: function(myXml) {
        var me = this,store;
        me.setLoading(true);
        store = new Ext.data.Store({
            pageSize: 100,
            leadingBufferZone: 100,
            proxy: new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
                actionMethods: { 
                    read: 'POST'
                },
                url: 'someUrl',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'I',
                    rootProperty: 'R'
                },
                extraParams: {
                    strIPXML: myXml
                }
            }),
            sortOnLoad : true,
            autoLoad: true,
            remoteFilter: true,
            fields: me.fields,
        });
        /*store.on('load', function(thistore, records , successful , operation , eOpts){
                me.store.loadData(thistore.data.items);
        });*/

        return store;
    },
```

Can anyone help me how to make it work. How to set the data in bufferedStore which i can easily able to set in `Ext.data.store`

Error : LoadData may not be used on a buffered store - the store is a map of remote data

Comment: Something smells really bad about your code. The store *should* already call `loadRecords` out of the box when you call the `load` operation, and put all your records into the store for you. You shouldn't have to call `loadData` to do that, especially not in a `load` listener. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Alexander I wish I could, But there is some xml operation is going on so I am not sure how can I make, The only query here is in first code I can assign the data to store but in second code I can't. How I can resolve the solution of loaddata. I cannot see `loadRecords ` in doc.

Comment: What's the purpose of having 2 stores that essentially have the same data?

Answer (score 1):

The ExtJS documentation for the store.load event says:

> Note: If you are using a buffered store, you should use prefetch.

Have you tried moving your function to the prefetch event to see if that works for you?

```
...
store.on('prefetch', function(...
```